# Skewed Generalized Error Distribution's (SGED) pdf

Tags: r, garch, matlab, estimation, distribution

I want to use the SGED distribution of Theodossiou for GARCH estimation, however, I am struggling to understand which is the correct pdf function of the distribution. Let me just say that the `rugarch` package cannot help me, as it estimates the GARCH with the SGED of Fernandez and Steel.

The distribution is introduced in the following paper in equation (10):
https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Panayiotis_Theodossiou/publication/228262554_Skewed_Generalized_Error_Distribution_of_Financial_Assets_and_Option_Pricing/links/546a5d070cf2397f783017af.pdf

This is the latest paper by Theodossiou and also has the pdf of the SGED distribution described as in equation (49): http://www.mfsociety.org/modules/modDashboard/uploadFiles/journals/MJ~0~p1a4fjq38m1k2p45t6481fob7rp4.pdf

This is a bit different definition of the SGED distribution, but the results are almost identical for the case I am considering.

There is one more specification in this paper on page 16: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/J_Mcdonald4/publication/227347472_Robust_estimation_with_flexible_parametric_distributions_estimation_of_utility_stock_betas/links/00b495225f8fe3511c000000.pdf
The A parameter is defined differently than in the first paper and the density looks differently.

Could you please advise me which pdf should I use as I am confused by such a number of definitions for the same thing and Theodossiou is the author or co-author of all the above-mentioned papers. If you know where I can find the definition of SGED by Fernandez and Steel I would also be grateful, as I am unable to find the pdf of the function. The help files for `rugarch` are not helpful on this matter.

Comment: Did you see this recent sgt R package : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sgt/vignettes/sgt.pdf   and https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sgt/sgt.pdf . You may find it usefull

Comment: @Malick I haven't seen this package, thank you! Although the pdf is differently specified I compared the results for the same parameters with the one from Theodossiou (2000) and the results are identical. Now I will try to incorporate this pdf into my GARCH calculations, as the previous one did not give satisfactory results. Could you please tell me, whether I should scale the densite of this distribution (as given on page 8 of the vignette) when calculating the likelihood function?

Comment: see my answer here http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22490/problem-with-obtaining-densities